# Has Hypnotoad ever been shown to hypnotize robots?

Tags: futurama

According to the Futurama Wiki:

> Hypnotoad is a large toad-like creature that has large oscillating multicolored eyes and emits a droning hum. His eyes glow all the time. The toad apparently uses these as a power of hypnotism on surrounding people and animals.

This does not explicitly say his powers do not work on robots, however I personally can't recall any instances where robots were hypnotized by Hypnotoad.  Is there ever a scene in the show where Hypnotoad is seen using his powers on robots?

Comment: His powers are pretty inconsistent; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZX_ce5M2G4

Comment: As hard as it is to prove a negative, I can't recall any instance where his powers worked on a robot. I've looked over each episode and on the three instances where he interacts with someone else, on each occasion it's only humans that are visible in the scene.

Comment: If anybody can recall scenes that involved Bender watching TV/seeing Hypnotoad, looking at how he reacted would probably be the best bet for figuring it out. (I'm drawing blanks right now, though.)